# installing RTL8821ce driver on New 2019 HP laptop nearly bricked lap F12 boot device selection no longer works

Tags: boot

Nearly bricked a new HP laptop trying one of this sites reported methods to load an RTL 8821ce driver. I now cannot get the F12 Boot device selection to function, so I cannot re-load the Ubuntu 18.04 and try again.

The laptop was very functional as a dual boot win 10 and 18.04, I just didn't have 18.04 wireless due to lack of driver.

As was pointed out formatting is easy, this is an exact cut and paste using the formatting previously allowed

Commands that broke it were;

The commands in the post just before this were correct except for the git pull. There is a username and password authentication requirement so you have to just go to the webpage -- https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce -- and download the .zip file. I then tried following through with changing the shell files to executable as suggested but when they ran there was a discrepency as to where the files needed to be located. (Im definitely not complaining, it can just be a bit confusing if you didn't really know what you were doing) The files need to be extracted to /usr/src/rtl8821ce-1.0.0 (make a new directory "rtl8821ce-1.0.0" inside /usr/src) and THEN chmod +x dkms-install.sh, everything should work out like gravy from there. Thank you so much whoever wrote this script. I dumped about 600 dollars into this badass machine and was thinking the wifi wouldn't work. Cheers.

Comment: Cut and paste works fine. You just have to format the text making use of [this editing guide](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).